# Swing hangs when being resized on a second display

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Main thread calls GUI() function that adds frame, menus, menuitems, and a scrollpane with jtable (DefaultTableModel).

If i place the running application to a second display/screen it hangs as soon i switch to a different application or when i try to resize it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI();
    }   
    public static void GUI(){
    JButton button;
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu menu, submenu;
    JMenuItem menuItem;

    window = new JFrame();
    window.setResizable(false);

    //menu
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menu = new JMenu("Start");
    submenu = new JMenu("New");
    menu.add(submenu);
    menuItem = new JMenuItem("menu1");
    menuItem.addActionListener(new buttonActionListener("m1"));
    submenu.add(menuItem);
    menuItem = new JMenuItem("menu2");
    menuItem.addActionListener(new buttonActionListener("m2"));
    submenu.add(menuItem);
    menuItem = new JMenuItem("menu3");
    menuItem.addActionListener(new buttonActionListener("m3"));
    submenu.add(menuItem);
    menuItem = new JMenuItem("menu4");
    menuItem.addActionListener(new buttonActionListener("m4"));
    submenu.add(menuItem);

    menuBar.add(menu); //start
    menu = new JMenu("Options");
    menuBar.add(menu); //options


    //top panel
    JPanel top = new JPanel();
    button = new JButton("Paste");
    button.addActionListener(new buttonActionListener("paste"));
    top.add(button);
    button = new JButton("Copy");
    button.addActionListener(new buttonActionListener("copy"));
    top.add(button);
    JButton start = new JButton("Start");
    start.addActionListener(new buttonActionListener("start"));
    top.add(start);

    //main panel with table
    main = new JScrollPane(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(); 
    table = new JTable(model);

    //bottom panel
    JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
    Creq = new JCheckBox();
    Creq.setSelected(true);
    item= new JTextField("item");
    comment = new JTextField("comment");
    target= new JTextField("target");
    req = new JTextField("requirement");
    bottom.add(Creq);
    bottom.add(req);
    bottom.add(item);
    depToUpdate.setVisible(true);
    bottom.add(target);
    targetDep.setVisible(true);
    bottom.add(comment);
    comment.setVisible(true);

    window.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    window.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    window.add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    window.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    window.pack();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setVisible(true);



}
```

Comment: if u cant publish then how we will solve ur problum how we will help u?

Comment: this works fine for me. It doesn't hang on my computer

Comment: i experience it on windows 7, works fine on ubuntu. also i have tried removing all buttonActionListeners, the result is the same

Comment: Where's the buttonActionlistener?  You're creating the whole SwingGUI with static methods, and you are not putting the components on the [Event Dispatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) thread.

Answer (score 1):

After spending way too much time fixing the code so that it would actually run in Java, I tested the GUI on my second monitor in Windows 8.  The GUI didn't do anything, but it didn't freeze either.

Here are the problems I fixed:

1. I moved the Swing GUI code into a regular class method (not static).
2. I put the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).  You **must always** create and execute your Swing components on the Event Dispatch thread.

Here's the version of the code I ran.

```
package snippet;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Snippet implements Runnable{

    private JCheckBox creq;

    private JFrame  window;

    private JScrollPane main;

    private JTable table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Snippet());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JButton button;
        JMenuBar menuBar;
        JMenu menu, submenu;
        JMenuItem menuItem;

        window = new JFrame();
        window.setResizable(false);

        // menu
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("Start");
        submenu = new JMenu("New");
        menu.add(submenu);
        menuItem = new JMenuItem("menu1");
//      menuItem.addActionListener(new buttonActionListener("m1"));
        submenu.add(menuItem);
        menuItem = new JMenuItem("menu2");
//      menuItem.addActionListener(new buttonActionListener("m2"));
        submenu.add(menuItem);
        menuItem = new JMenuItem("menu3");
//      menuItem.addActionListener(new buttonActionListener("m3"));
        submenu.add(menuItem);
        menuItem = new JMenuItem("menu4");
//      menuItem.addActionListener(new buttonActionListener("m4"));
        submenu.add(menuItem);

        menuBar.add(menu); // start
        menu = new JMenu("Options");
        menuBar.add(menu); // options

        // top panel
        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton("Paste");
//      button.addActionListener(new buttonActionListener("paste"));
        top.add(button);
        button = new JButton("Copy");
//      button.addActionListener(new buttonActionListener("copy"));
        top.add(button);
        JButton start = new JButton("Start");
//      start.addActionListener(new buttonActionListener("start"));
        top.add(start);

        // main panel with table
//      main = new JScrollPane(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
//              ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        table = new JTable(model);
        main = new JScrollPane(table);


        // bottom panel
        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        creq = new JCheckBox();
        creq.setSelected(true);
        JTextField item = new JTextField("item");
        JTextField comment = new JTextField("comment");
        JTextField target = new JTextField("target");
        JTextField req = new JTextField("requirement");
        bottom.add(creq);
        bottom.add(req);
        bottom.add(item);
//      depToUpdate.setVisible(true);
        bottom.add(target);
//      targetDep.setVisible(true);
        bottom.add(comment);
        comment.setVisible(true);

        window.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        window.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        window.add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        window.pack();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```